# Best way to have data link in class composition

Tags: c++

So say I have A, which contains object B:

```
class A {
private:
   B b;
};
```

And I want to share real-time data between these two. I was thinking about passing a pointer of a struct with all the data I want to share into the constructor of "b", but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: You don't need composition to share data between objects. Just pass the data (by value, reference or (smart) pointer) when calling the functions. Perhaps if you explain *why* you need composition, and *why* you need to share data, what the *actual* problem you try to solve is, then we might be able to better help you with a solution.

Comment: What is real-time data?

Comment: For my application these need to be two separate objects, and A and B need to share data. I was thinking the best way to do this is to have them access the same memory, which is why I was thinking passing a pointer to B so they can share the same memory. I mean the data that A sees should be the same data B sees by "real-time data".